# Java/ Сравнение нескольких переменных и выдача результата на их основании

Tags: java

Необходимо написать код, который будет проверять переменные(точнее то,что в них заложено) и на основании чисел в переменных выдавать результат, который можно из них получить. Используя булевые переменные и операторы сравнения. То есть даны какие то исходные данные и что можно получить на их основании. Числа в переменных могут меняться, и в зависимости от них должно выдаваться то блюдо, которое можно получить из заданного кол-ва ингредиентов. Пробовала уже всеми возможными способами, не могу сформулировать правильно.

```
public class Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int milkAmount = 200; // ml
        int powderAmount = 5; // g
        int eggsCount = 3; // items


        //powder - 400 g, milk - 1 l, eggs -3
        System.out.println("Pancakes");

        //milk - 300 ml, eggs - 5
        System.out.println("Omelette");

    }
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте про коллекции и массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Так и пишете.

```
if (milkAmount == 400 && powderAmount == 1 && eggs == 3) {
    System.out.println("Pancakes");
}

if (milkAmount == 300 && eggs == 5) {
    System.out.println("Omelette");
}
```

Но лучше начните с изучения ветвлений.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте if()
В качестве условия сравнивайте свои переменные с необходимыми абсолютными значениями.
Например:

```
if(milkAmount == 1000 && eggs == 3 && powder == 400){
    System.out.println("Pancakes");
}
```

Где == - оператор сравнения РАВНО, а && - логический оператор И.